# Unable access HEY_CURRENT_USER Environment variable in Rest service launched through Windows service

Tags: c#

`Process restService = Process.Start("F:\\RestService\\RestService.exe");`
Code is simple.
I have a created a windows service(C#) under local system account.
I have to launch a Rest service(C++) through it.
That rest service uses Environment variable FMS_HOME for FCC from HKEY_CURRENT_USER section.
When I run rest service standalone, it works fine.
But when I run rest service through windows service, FMS_HOME is not found.
How to solve this?

Comment: show some code - how do you start he process?

Comment: You need to post some code to understand your problem

Answer (score 4):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as it's name implies is a key that stores data for the current user. I assume that you are using an integrated account to run your service, something like "Network Service", so you will not see the key because the account is not the same one that created the entry.

To solve it you have two options: store the keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or launch your service with the same account that created the entries in the registry (I would not recommend it as it may create security problems).

Comment: Yes registry was created with another user. But I moved this entry from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I think if my user has access to do that then it should have access through rest service or window service also

Comment: @VikasB No it will not, each user has an individual`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` storage. Even if your user has administrator access that user has it's own `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` storage, so you will access it and not the one of the user who created the key.

Comment: but I can see that environment variable in my HKEY_CURRENT_USER section. So why I can't access it through rest service code?

Comment: YOU can see it, under YOUR account, not under the account that runs the service.

Comment: Window service is running under local system. Can we launch Rest service such that it uses HKEY_CURRENT_USER section?

Comment: @VikasB Run it under the account you have created the registry entry